# Подсчет рядов в DataTable по столбцу

Tags: asp.net

Есть `DataTable table`, которая содержит информацию, например:

```
Title | Description | Number 
Заголовок 1 | Описание 1 | 1
Заголовок 2 | Описание 2 | 15
Заголовок 3 | Описание 3 | 15
Заголовок 4 | Описание 4 | 15
```

Я хотел бы преобразовать её к виду:

```
  Number | Count
    1    | 1
    15   | 3
```

Каким образом это возможно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я не ошибаюсь можно вот так

```
var groupedData = from b in table.AsEnumerable()
                  group b by b.Field<int>("Number") into g
                  select new
                  {
                      Number= g.Key,
                      Count = g.Count()   
                  };
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hvmSV0)

Comment: Попробовал, деббагер показывает, что подсчет не ведеться и количество всегда 0.

Comment: @DisguisePerceptron добавил пример в fidle

Comment: Значит ошибка где-то в моей части кода. Думаю я сам это смогу поправить. Спасибо за помощь в решении.